# Undefined index foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I have searched internet and stack for hours now but I just cant find an answer to my problem.

I have an array with postcodes and want to check the distance between them.

```
function afstand($postcode, $postcodeBestemming) {
    $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" . $postcode . "&destinations=" . $postcodeBestemming . "&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false";

    $data   = @file_get_contents($url);
    $result = json_decode($data, true);
    print_r($result);  //outputs the array
}
```

My array looks like this:

```
id  klant_id    datum   datum_afspraak  postcode    max_afstand
1   1   2016-07-13  2016-07-21  5263CL  90
2   2   2016-07-13  2016-07-29  2344HA  20
3   3   2016-07-21  2016-07-26  3546AR  27
```

When I go over them with a foreach loop it only fills in the first array element.

```
foreach($klanten as $klant) {
  afstand('3746AB', $klant['postcode']);
}
```

The first element is fine but when it comes to the second element the destination is empty

```
Array ( [destination_addresses] => Array ( [0] => ) [origin_addresses] => Array ( [0] => 5521 KL Eersel, Netherlands ) [rows] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [elements] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [status] => NOT_FOUND ) ) ) ) [status] => OK )
```

No matter how I format the array, it just isn`t filling in the destination

EDIT:
for the request, here is the full code:

```
foreach($offertes as $offerte) {
    print $garagePostcode;
    print '<br/>';
    print $offerte['max_afstand'];
    print '<br/>';
    print $offerte['id'];
    print '<br/>';  
    print $offerte['postcode'];
    print '<br/>';
    $afstand = afstand($garagePostcode, $offerte['postcode']);
    //print $afstand;
    var_dump($offerte['postcode']);
    print '<br/>';
    print '<br/>';
    unset($postcode);
}
```

And the function

```
function afstand($postcode, $postcodeBestemming) {
    $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" . $postcode . "&destinations=" . $postcodeBestemming . "&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false";

    $data   = @file_get_contents($url);
    $result = json_decode($data, true);
    print_r($result);  //outputs the array

    $distance = $result["rows"][0]["elements"][0]["distance"]["value"] / 1000;

    return $distance;
}
```

And the output:

```
id  klant_id    datum   datum_afspraak  postcode    max_afstand
1   1   2016-07-13  2016-07-21  5527CL  90
2   2   2016-07-13  2016-07-29  2344HA  20
3   3   2016-07-21  2016-07-26  3546AR  27

5521KL
90
1
5527CL
Array ( [destination_addresses] => Array ( [0] => 5527 CL Hapert, Netherlands ) [origin_addresses] => Array ( [0] => 5521 KL Eersel, Netherlands ) [rows] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [elements] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [distance] => Array ( [text] => 6.1 km [value] => 6112 ) [duration] => Array ( [text] => 12 mins [value] => 706 ) [status] => OK ) ) ) ) [status] => OK ) string(6) "5527CL"

5521KL
20
2
2344HA
Array ( [destination_addresses] => Array ( [0] => ) [origin_addresses] => Array ( [0] => 5521 KL Eersel, Netherlands ) [rows] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [elements] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [status] => NOT_FOUND ) ) ) ) [status] => OK )
Notice: Undefined index: distance in /var/www/rama/functions.php on line 176
string(6) "2344HA"

5521KL
27
3
3546AR
Array ( [destination_addresses] => Array ( [0] => ) [origin_addresses] => Array ( [0] => 5521 KL Eersel, Netherlands ) [rows] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [elements] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [status] => NOT_FOUND ) ) ) ) [status] => OK )
Notice: Undefined index: distance in /var/www/rama/functions.php on line 176
string(6) "3546AR"
```

Comment: Have you tried manually typing out the urls and visiting them with a browser to see if you get any errors?

Comment: Can you provide the correct code? There's nothing returned from `afstand` and you're not actually storing or returning the $result anywhere.

Comment: Correct, its been outputted with print_r. When I do this manually it works just fine. When I change rows in the database it`s always only the first row which is checked and by the second row it returns nothing.

Comment: What apokryos is saying is: you're providing too little code to be able to help. So far it's just a guessing game. (not saying that you won't find your answer, just that it's fairly unlikely, if you don't provide more code)